# how to launch jupyterlab from a python conda env with a single Windows DOS command

Tags: jupyter-lab

I have installed Jupyter Lab in one of my conda python environments which I named `jupyter`.

I would like to launch this Jupyter Lab by clicking an icon in the Windows taskbar but don't know how to specify the appropriate DOS command in the Target box for the icon.

I used to use the following DOS command when launching Jupyter Lab from my `base` environment, but this obviously wouldn't work for launching Jupyter Lab from my `jupyter` env

`%windir%\System32\cmd.exe "/K" C:\Users\%username%\anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\Users\%username%\anaconda3 & jupyter lab && exit`

So, my question is what DOS command should I use to launch Jupyter Lab from my `jupyter` env?